# How can I use both Resource and MenuItem in Admin menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, admin-on-rest

So I have Admin with all the resources that I need and it works great.
But I also need one little menu item that would just open a simple form with a button.

I created Menu.js like it's described here:

https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest//AdminResource.html#menu

And added it to my admin.

But after that I see only items that I have in that Menu, but not resources.
How can I have them both: Resources  and MenuItems in that menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the framework's `Menu.js` for inspiration.

- You need to loop through the passed in `resources` param and create `<MenuItem>`s for each resource
- Add your own `<MenuItem>`s
- Add the `{logout}` if you are using authentication

Ie:

```
import React from 'react';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default ({ resources, onMenuTap, logout }) => (
    <div>
        { resources.map(resource => {
          return <MenuItem
            key={resource.name}
            containerElement={<Link to={`/${resource.name}`} />}
            primaryText={resource.options.label}
            onTouchTap={onMenuTap}
          />
        })}

        <MenuItem key="download" containerElement={<Link to="/download" />} primaryText="Download" onTouchTap={onMenuTap} />

        {logout}
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the documentation, you currently have to add them by yourself